# Issue with username and password variables in sqlite3 and tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I need my program to take the inputs from the entry fields in the Tkinter window and run them through the database to log the user in, however, it says that I have a binding problem with my parameter 0 (username), and I assume this would also occur with my password variable aswell.

```py
def loginfunc():
        while True:
            with sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db') as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
            find_user = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
            cursor.execute(find_user, (username, password))
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results:
                for i in results:
                    print ("welcome "+i[1]+"")
                    break
            else:
                print ("Username or password incorrect")
                login()
            break
```

```py
def login():
        screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
        screen1.title("Login")
        screen1.geometry("300x250")

        global username
        global password
        username = StringVar()
        password = StringVar()

        Label(screen1, text = "Please enter your username and password below: ").pack()
        Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
        Label(screen1, text = "Username: ").pack()
        Entry(screen1, textvariable = username).pack()
        Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
        Label(screen1, text = "Password: ").pack()
        Entry(screen1, textvariable = password).pack()
        Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
        Button(screen1, text = "Login", width = 10, height = 1, command=loginfunc).pack()
```

```py
File "C:\Users\notmyname\Desktop\NEA PROPER.py", line 90, in loginfunc
     cursor.execute(find_user, (username, password))
     sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says your binding parameters are of an unsupported type. 
The datatype of *username* and *password* is **StringVar** which is a Tkinter(TCL) in-built type.

StringVar does not provide value by directly using it, you need to call on on StringVar object the **get method** to get value as a string which you can then pass on to your cursor.execute call.

[Refer here to know about StringVar get method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Try this:

```
cursor.execute(find_user, (username.get(), password.get()))
```